# Django administration styling: Change "Site administration" and subheadings

Tags: python, django, templates, styles

Am trying to style my admin page in Django on the left hand section with the title "Site administration" and the subheadings I would like to change the background and text colors of the  subheadings where the list of tables are shown with the add and change icons. I have tried the following but to no success.

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'Kraken site admin' %}{% endblock %}
{% block extrastyle %}
<style>
#header{background-color: #3c3c3a;}
#branding h1{ color: #ff9919; }
#branding h2{ background-color: #3c3c3a;}
.module h2,.module caption, .inline-group h2 { margin:0; padding:2px 5px 3px 5px; font-size:11px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; background-color:#ff9919; color:#9A6002; }

</style>
{% endblock %}
{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name" >{% trans 'My Administration' %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% comment %}<div style="padding:4px 14px 4px 10px;">
        <a style="border-right: 1px solid white; padding-right:14px;" href="../">Customer UI</a>
        <a style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:5px;" href="{% url "admin_thread_list" %}">Thread List</a>{% endcomment %}
</div>{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the {% block content_title %}{% endblock %}just before {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %} and added in my Title in between: `{% block content_title %} My Title{% endblock %}` in the `base_site.html` file in your `templates/admin/` directory, it successfully removed the "Site Administration" string